# Non-existing setting in Doctrine bridge in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sylius

I've just installed [Sylius Settings bundle](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusSettingsBundle/installation.html).

After composer finished its work, and after setting everything as in docs (link above), enabling Sylius Settings bundle causes the following error:

```
The service definition "doctrine.orm.default_metadata_driver" does not exist.
```

I searched for this keywords (whole service name) for the whole vendors folder, but it found it only in some Doctrine test files, nowhere else. Anyone knows what is it about? Perhaps it's just a "legacy bug" in SF2?

Or perhaps not. I found this class for the moment:

Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass

in particular this part (constructor):

```
public function __construct($driver, array $namespaces, array $managerParameters, $enabledParameter = false, array $aliasMap = array())
{
    $managerParameters[] = 'doctrine.default_entity_manager';
    parent::__construct(
        $driver,
        $namespaces,
        $managerParameters,
        'doctrine.orm.%s_metadata_driver',
        $enabledParameter,
        'doctrine.orm.%s_configuration',
        'addEntityNamespace',
        $aliasMap
    );
}
```

(Note: "'doctrine.orm.%s_metadata_driver'," as a partly hard-coded param)

I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that I'm not using ORM, but PHPCR-ODM as a default connection type (ORM is non-default additional connection layer).

config.yml part referring to the bundle:

```
sylius_settings:
    driver: doctrine/orm

doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        my_apc_metadata_cache:
            type: apc
            namespace: metadata_cache_ns
        my_apc_query_cache:
            namespace: query_cache_ns
            apc: ~
        sylius_settings:
            type: file_system
```

Nothing extra ordinary.

Comment: Can you add you bundle listing (the way they are ordered) and the config.yml. Could be an issue with the order.

Comment: @coudenysj thx for reply. Well my config.yml is quite big, but the required config for Settings bundle is very short on the contrary. In fact there are two options only: one can place sylius_settings after or before 
doctrine_cache. In both cases I get: "The service definition "doctrine.orm.default_metadata_driver" does not exist.". I updated my info with the interesting config part.